# Parse ado.net web response in android

Tags: android

I have one web service whose response is like:

```
   <xml>
   <id>1</id>
   <title>name</title>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
    <d:firstname>bindal</d:firstname>
    <d:lastname>kadakia</d.lastname>
     .
     ..
     ..
    </m.properties>
    </xml>
```

i am parsing this xml using sax parser by matching local name tags  when i parse id and title tags i got its values and when i parse content tag it gives all values inside content tag but when i parse "d:firstname>" tag i got nothing
I don't know how to parse this type of xml please give some solution thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use third String parameter:

```
startElement(String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts)
```

From docs:
qName - The qualified name (with prefix), or the empty string if qualified names are not available.